# Replace parts of a URL with .htaccess Rewrite Rules

Tags: .htaccess

Good morning,

I´m want to change the urls of my website to google seo optimized ones. The way I have at the moment, does not work well. My website is available in 3 languages, English, German and French. The names of the sections are stored in the database. To select the language, tags are used [de][/de][en][/en][fr][/fr]

After changing the URL to the Seo one, that tags are still in the url, what looks not nice.

I changed actual that URL

`http://localhost/AAMFULL/modules/merchandise/viewcat.php?cid=4`

into this one

`http://localhost/AAMFULL/merchandise/[de]Anziehsachen[/de][en]Clothings[/en][fr]Vêtements[/fr]/cat,4,0,200,0,list.html`

No I have seen, it´s possible to give the htaccess a language tag, to get the right part of the URL. How does that work?

If that not work, how can I change the url to look nicer? like this:

`http://localhost/AAMFULL/merchandise/de-Anziehsachen/en-Clothings/fr-Vêtements/cat,4,0,200,0,list.html`

Or do you have another idea?

That´s the code inside my htaccess

htaccess rules file:

#SEO .Htaccess setting

```
RewriteRule ^merchandise.([a-z]+).([0-9.]+)/  modules/merchandise/index.php?seoOp=$1&seoArg=$2
RewriteRule ^merchandise/submit.html                                                                                         modules/merchandise/submit.php  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/submit.php                                                                                         modules/merchandise/submit.php  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/ratephoto.php                                                                                         modules/merchandise/ratephoto.php  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/cat,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html                                         modules/merchandise/viewcat.php?cid=$1&uid=$2&num=$3&pos=$4&view=$5  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/rss,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+).rss                                            modules/merchandise/rss.php?cid=$1&uid=$2&num=$3&pos=$4&view=$5  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/index,([0-9]+),([0-9]+).html                                                                         modules/merchandise/index.php?num=$1&pos=$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/rate,([0-9]+).html                                                                                 modules/merchandise/ratephoto.php?lid=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/top,([0-9]+),([0-9]+).html                                                                         modules/merchandise/topten.php?hit=$1&rate=$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/index.php                                                                                     modules/merchandise/index.php  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/comment_(.*?)                                                                                  modules/merchandise/comment_$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/photo.php(.*?)                                                                                  modules/merchandise/photo.php$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/viewcat.php(.*?)                                                                              modules/merchandise/viewcat.php$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/ratephoto.php(.*?)                                                                              modules/merchandise/ratephoto.php$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/list.tag.php(.*?)                                                                              modules/merchandise/list.tag.php$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/view.tag.php(.*?)                                                                              modules/merchandise/view.tag.php$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/submit.php(.*?)                                                                                modules/merchandise/submit.php?$2&title=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/submit,([0-9]+).html                                                                            modules/merchandise/submit.php?cid=$2&title=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/cat,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html                                     modules/merchandise/viewcat.php?cid=$2&uid=$3&num=$4&pos=$5&view=$6  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/rss,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+).rss                                     modules/merchandise/rss.php?cid=$2&uid=$3&num=$4&pos=$5&view=$6  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/edit,([0-9]+),([0-9]+).html                                                            modules/merchandise/editphoto.php?lid=$3&cid=$4   [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/rate,([0-9]+),([0-9]+).html                                                            modules/merchandise/ratephoto.php?lid=$3&cid=$4   [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/submit.php?cid=([0-9]+)                                                                modules/merchandise/submit.php?cid=$3&title=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/comment_(.*?)                                                                          modules/merchandise/comment_$3  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/photo.php(.*?)                                                                          modules/merchandise/photo.php$3  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/viewcat.php(.*?)                                                                          modules/merchandise/viewcat.php$3  [L,NC,QSA,P]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/ratephoto.php(.*?)                                                                      modules/merchandise/ratephoto.php$3  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/list.tag.php(.*?)                                                                      modules/merchandise/list.tag.php$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/view.tag.php(.*?)                                                                      modules/merchandise/view.tag.php$2  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/index.php                                                                                 modules/merchandise/index.php  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)/(.*?)/([0-9]+),([0-9]+).html                                                                 modules/merchandise/photo.php?lid=$3&cid=$4  [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*?)                                                                                                 modules/merchandise/$1  [L,NC,QSA]
```

The excemple Url are from my testsystem. The original URL of the live version from that excample is

https://kenner-mask.com/modules/merchandise/viewcat.php?cid=4

In the red section in the header you can see the title from the seo url and how it change with the different languages

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for letting know your htaccess file. Could you please do mention FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite? Sorry but your current question it is not clear, thank you.

Comment: Have add a live url.

Comment: Your url `http://localhost/AAMFULL/merchandise/[de]Anziehsachen[/de][en]Clothings[/en][fr]Vêtements[/fr]/cat,4,0,200,0,list.html` means is it: `http://localhost/AAMFULL/merchandise/[de]Anziehsachen` should be rewritten? OR something else? Also your html file has `,` comma in it, is it right samples. Kindly confirm it once, thank you.

Comment: I have changed my post, I hjope it is more clear. The SEO URL is the one as it work live on my testsystgem, include the , (comma)